# Pass items to BaseAdapter from parsed XML

Tags: android, xml, gridview, baseadapter

I'm having a problem with adding items to BaseAdapter which stands as content of GridView. It looks like this if I pass items manually:

```
private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Context context;

    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        items.add(new Item("Burton - Ruler", R.drawable.bt_burton_ruler));
        items.add(new Item("DC - Ceptor", R.drawable.bt_dc_ceptor));
}
```

and how it visually looks:

[image]

`Item` class is:

```
private class Item
    {
        final String name;
        final int picId;

        Item(String name, int drawableId)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.picId = drawableId;
        }
    }
```

And since it's a bad approach to add content manually I'm trying to pass it from parsed XML file (using Xstream). It parses Ok. Here's how content of parsed ArrayList looks like:

[image]

And here's how I try to pass these values into Adapter:

```
public MyAdapter(Context context) throws Exception
    {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("xml/boots.xml");  // load file
            XStream xstream = new XStream();
            xstream.processAnnotations(Boots.class);
            xstream.processAnnotations(IdBoots.class);
            Boots boots= (Boots) xstream.fromXML(reader);

            for (int j = 0; j < boards.getIds().size(); j++) {
                IdBoots idBoot= (IdBoots)boards.getIds().get(j);
                int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(idBoot.getPicture(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
                items.add(new Item(idBoot.getBoard(), id));
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }
}
```

As you see I'm trying to get id of `drawable/picture_name.jpg` is such a way (probably problem is here):

`int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(idBoot.getPicture(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());`

But still id doesn't work. It compiles and stuff, but the GridView remains empty.

And yea, here's how `Boots` class looks like:

```
@XStreamAlias("BOOTS")
public class Boots<E> {
     @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "id")
     public List<E> ids = new ArrayList<E>();

//region GETTERS-SETTERS
     public void setIds(ArrayList<E> temp){
         this.ids = temp;
     }
     public List<E> getIds(){
         return ids;
     }
//    endregion
}

@XStreamAlias("id")
class IdBoots {

    @XStreamAlias("boot")
    private String boot;

    @XStreamAlias("description")
    private String description;

    @XStreamAlias("price")
    private String price;

    @XStreamAlias("riding_level")
    private String ridingLevel;

    @XStreamAlias("lacing_type")
    private String lacingType;

    @XStreamAlias("picture")
    private String picture;

    <<GETTERS - SETTERS HERE>>
}
```

Sincerely thanks in advance for help

Comment: just add a paremeter like List<Item> list to your constructor of your adapter, the Override your getView and getItem method in your adapter to your needs

Comment: I have them both overriden. But how can I apply these `getView()` and `getItem()` in code? I need rather something like `setItem()`